# asp.net utility to allow remote writeline?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, remote-debugging

I had a simple utility a couple years back that I could run on my local machine, and it would monitor a server without the need for remote debugging, or for anything to be running on the server.

I could add the equivalent of Console.Writeline to the code (I can't remember if it was console, debug, or trace) and could monitor it by running the utility on my desktop machine.

I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You might be thinking of SysInternals DebugView which picks up standard output. It doesn't work remotely though.

Comment: This was something which worked remotely, because I used it to monitor a production server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create WCF or Webservice that will check what you need and return you XML or Json.
And client will invoke this service

Answer (score 0):

the standard way is to use Trace.Write method in your code and watch what's going on by using
http://myserver/Trace.axd (it will tell you to enable tracing in web.config)

This allows you to see much more data than just your string - it shows complete context plus it actually times all the traces so you can see how much time different actions took